# UNIX Shell Script to bulk import products data into Magento

Tags: magento2

I am looking for sample shell script which will

1. select all newly created products from ERP
2. Create CSV file
3. Call Magento REST API to bulk import products into Magento

I can do steps #1 and #2, But I am not sure how to call REST API to load CSV file into Magento.